# Using Record Edit Form on Local Development Server

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

Does anyone know if there are known bugs with using record-edit-form on a local development server?  The record loads just fine in the org but doesn't seem to load when attempting to load it from the local development server.  I noticed that the onload function never seems to fire and that the onerror function doesn't fire either.

```
    <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Case" record-type-id={recordTypeId} onload={handleRecordLoaded} onsubmit={handleSubmit} onerror={handleError} onsuccess={handleSuccess}>
      ...
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem running the basic example code for "Creating a Record" in the [record-edit-form component reference documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation).

I was able to fix my issue with that specific example by adding the `lightning__Tab` target to my js-meta.xml file, so that it looked like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <apiVersion>47.0</apiVersion>
  <isExposed>false</isExposed>
  <targets>
    <target>lightning__Tab</target>
  </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Still unsure how the server works, so can't provide any magic insight. Just the result of my tinkering... so please let me know if that solves your issue!

Answer (score 0):

While developing in the Local Development Server, try hard-coding variables like `recordId`.   The problem is the Local Development Server doesn't know how to get a record context.

It'd be nice if devs could have a way to inject FlexiPage context, e.g. through a URL parameter, but alas, this isn't supported today.